# How do they go from implicit partial differentiation in this problem to solving with a determinant?

Tags: determinant, partial-derivative

In this book I'm studying I've come across a problem where the author solves a partial differentiation problem using determinants. I'm somewhat familiar with them, but I don't see how they derive the answer from the two they started with:

> \begin{cases} 
>       v+log\left|u\right|=xy \\
>       u+log\left|v\right|=x-y 
>    \end{cases}
>   \begin{cases} 
>       \frac{1}{u}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}=y \\
>       \frac{1}{v}\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=1
>    \end{cases}

So in retrospect they started with the first bracket above with two equations in it and the four variables *v*, *u*, *x* and *y*, and then used implicit partial differentiation to arrive at the second bracket.

Are dependent and independent variables treated differently when taking the derivative?

Lastly, they moved into lesser-known territory for me and solved the second bracket for $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}$:

> $$ \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{
> \begin{vmatrix}
> yu & u \\
> v & 1 \\
> \end{vmatrix}}
> {\begin{vmatrix}
> 1 & u \\
> v & 1 \\
> \end{vmatrix}}=
> \frac{{u}\left(y-v\right)}{1-uv}$$

How is it that they go from the bracket to that determinant?

Thank you,
Brandon

Comment: Going from the 2nd bracket to the quotient of determinants is *Cramer's Rule*, q.v. Going from the 1st bracket to the second, are you sure you have it right? It seems to me that the $1/v$ should be $1/u$, and vice versa.

Comment: You're right, I mis-copied that from the text, my bad. Thank you for your comment, I'll look into that rule..

Comment: Thanks! found something about it on Wolfram, I'll study it and see if it still doesn't makes sense.

Comment: Good. Please come back to report on what you find.

Comment: Okay, so I think it comes from the vector cross product? Perhaps they're treating the partial derivatives as vectors, and in that way $$ \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} = yu-u\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}} \implies \begin{vmatrix} yu & u \\ v & 1 \end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: If that is the case, then how is it that $ \frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}} = v$ ?

Comment: I don't understand your last comment --- I don't see $${\partial v\over\partial x}=v$$ anywhere. The second bracket is two linear equations in the two unknowns $\partial u/\partial x$ and $\partial v/\partial x$, and they are solving that system using Cramer's Rule, together with some elementary facts about determinants.

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks:

- Take into account that $x$ and $y$ seem to be the *indepedent variables* of your problem. Then, it turns out that:
  $$ \frac{\partial (xy)}{\partial x} =  \frac{\partial (x)}{\partial x} y +  x\frac{\partial (y)}{\partial x} = y, \quad  \frac{\partial (x-y)}{\partial x} =  \frac{\partial (x)}{\partial x} -  \frac{\partial (y)}{\partial x} = 1,$$ since $\partial_x y = 0$.
- In order to come up with the expression for $u_x$ and $v_x$, the Cramer's rule has been used. Note that you can write the second bracket as follows:
  $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
  1 & u \\
  v & 1 \\
  \end{array}\right) \mathbf{U} = \left(\begin{array}{c}
  y u \\
  v \\
  \end{array}\right), $$ where $\mathbf{U}=(\partial_x u , \partial_x v)$ and we have multiplied the first row by $u$ and the second by $v$.

I hope this helps.

Cheers!